# Просто прочитать из файла

Tags: файлы, pascal

Хочу научиться читать из файлов в Паскале.
Прочитал литературу, но простых действий типа readln() не нашел. Обьясните максимально простые действия.
Сваял говнокод, выбивает ошибку (error 100):

```
program 1;
var
f:FILE of STRING;
a:STRING;
begin
Assign(f,'tct.txt');
rewrite(f);
read(f,a);
writeln(a);
readln;
end.
```

Кто может обьяснить (по возможности и как писать в файл)

Задание : прочитать текст из файла .dat и создать файл с результатом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для работы с текстовыми файлами в паскале есть специальный тип: TEXT.

```
program reader;
var
    f : Text;
    a : string;
begin
    assign(f, "fileName.ext"); { связываем переменную с файлом }
    reset(f); { открываем для чтения }
    while not eof(f) do begin { пока не конец файла }
        read(f, a); { читаем из файла }
        writeln(a); { выводим на экран }
    end;
    close(f); { закрываем файл }
end.

program writer;
var
    f : text;
    a : string;
begin
    assign(f, "fileName.ext"); { связываем переменную и файл }
    rewrite(f); { открываем для записи (файл будет перезаписан, для дозаписи нужно использовать append(f); }
    write(f, a); { пишем в файл }
    close(f); { закрываем файл }
end.
```

Comment: спасибо! но:
1)в чем была ошибка
2)как создать НОВЫЙ ФАЙЛ?
3)что если файл .dat ?

Comment: @iamqwerty: `rewrite` создаст новый файл, если его ещё нет. Если есть, он затрётся. Будет работать с любым расширением, конечно.

Ошибка была в том, что `rewrite` открывает файл на запись, а не на чтение. Так что читать бы не получилось.

Comment: не **TEXT** а **TEXTFILE** 

Тип **Text** уже устарел и является эквивалентным типу **TextFile**.

[Хороший онлайн справочник по Delphi][1] 
[1]: http://delphibasics.ru

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!